# How can I resolve all these errors from folium?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, folium

I am trying to create a map following [this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWvLida5wcM&t=941s) I am using almost the exact same code as in the tutorial, but get a series I am unsure how to begin resolving, anyone have any thoughts on how I could start resolving?

Here is my code below. I think my table merge worked okay because it appears correctly when I print the table, but I think things start going downhill with the choropleth function.

'''

```
import geopandas 
import pandas as pd
import folium


url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_meat_consumption'
tables = pd.read_html(url)
table = tables[0]


world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))


table = world.merge(table, how='left', left_on=['name'], right_on=['Country'])
pd.options.display.width = 4000
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 188)
table = table.dropna(subset=['kg/person (2002)[9][note 1]'])


meat_map = folium.Map()

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=table,                  
    name='choropleth',                  
    data=table,                     
    columns=['Country', 'kg/person (2002)[9][note 1]'], 
    key_on ='feature.properties.name',
    fill_color ='YlGnBu',     
    fill_opacity = 0.7,
    line_opacity = 0.2,
   legend_name = "Meat consumption in kg/person"
).add_to(meat_map)
```

here is my error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-b9be599a18fa> in <module>
     10 meat_map = folium.Map()
     11 
---> 12 folium.Choropleth(
     13     geo_data=table,
     14     name='choropleth',

~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in __init__(self, geo_data, data, columns, key_on, bins, fill_color, nan_fill_color, fill_opacity, nan_fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, line_opacity, name, legend_name, overlay, control, show, topojson, smooth_factor, highlight, **kwargs)
   1287                 smooth_factor=smooth_factor)
   1288         else:
-> 1289             self.geojson = GeoJson(
   1290                 geo_data,
   1291                 style_function=style_function,

~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in __init__(self, data, style_function, highlight_function, name, overlay, control, show, smooth_factor, tooltip, embed, popup, zoom_on_click, marker)
    497         self.marker = marker
    498 
--> 499         self.data = self.process_data(data)
    500 
    501         if self.style or self.highlight:

~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in process_data(self, data)
    540             if hasattr(data, 'to_crs'):
    541                 data = data.to_crs('EPSG:4326')
--> 542             return json.loads(json.dumps(data.__geo_interface__))
    543         else:
    544             raise ValueError('Cannot render objects with any missing geometries'

~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\json\__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    229         cls is None and indent is None and separators is None and
    230         default is None and not sort_keys and not kw):
--> 231         return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
    232     if cls is None:
    233         cls = JSONEncoder

~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\json\encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    197         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201             chunks = list(chunks)

~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\json\encoder.py in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    255                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    258 
    259 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\json\encoder.py in default(self, o)
    177 
    178         """
--> 179         raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    180                         f'is not JSON serializable')
    181 

TypeError: Object of type MultiPolygon is not JSON serializable
'''
```

Comment: works without errors for me...  `print(folium.__version__, geopandas.__version__, pd.__version__)` gives `0.12.1 0.9.0 1.2.4`

Comment: even if you try to save or display the map? I get: unknown 0.9.0 1.2.3

Comment: It could be something wrong with your folium install. Worth reinstalling

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what must be going on.